# Reading data from a csv file - File not found exception for a valid source

Tags: java, csv

I have a problem reading a csv file from the web. I get a File not found exception. That's the source: http://data.okfn.org/data/core/s-and-p-500-companies/r/constituents.csv
How could it be the file cannot be found if I can easily open it ? what am I missing here ?

```
package Investing;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    String csvFile = "http://data.okfn.org/data/core/s-and-p-500-     companies/r/constituents.csv";
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";


    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            System.out.println(data);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Download that file onto local manually and then use filereader.

Comment: @SMA The content of the file can change, that's why I want to read the data directly from the web. There's no option of doing so ?

Comment: Then better you read from url or download the file and then read the file.

Comment: @SMA can you add the relevant code to do one of the options (reading from a url or downloading the file) ?

Comment: @SMA I managed to read the file from the URL.Thanks!  God bless the internet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileReader is used for local files. 
See: [Read remote .csv file using opencsv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513697/read-remote-csv-file-using-opencsv) for reading a remote cvs file.

Another alternative to read a remote file in:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String csvFile = "http://data.okfn.org/data/core/s-and-p-500-companies/r/constituents.csv";

    try {
        URL url12 = new URL(csvFile);
        URLConnection urlConn = url12.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(inStream);

        String line = buff.readLine();
        line  = buff.readLine();
        while (line != null) {

            System.out.println(line);
            line = buff.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. I used that code and changed it a bit.

Comment: What's the difference between opening a connection and getting an inputStream, and opening a stream and use csvreader class (like the link you posted) ? I guess the way described here is general and the other one supports CSV files, but what's the benefit of using csvReader class ? for what purposes csvReader is good for ?

Comment: I am afraid I can't answer it, but fell free to post a new question.